# Read latest file grouped by monthYear in directory in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have multiple files in a directory.
File name are similar to those added in picture 1.
[image]

I want to read only latest file for each month from the directory in pyspark as dataframe.
Expected files to be read as shown in picture 2
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import glob

path = '/your_path/'
form = 'csv'
os.chdir(path)
files_list = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(form))

dic = {}


prefix = files_list[0][:4]
suffix = files_list[0][-4:]

for i in range(0, len(files_list)):
    
    ym = files_list[i][4:12][:6]
    d = files_list[i][4:12][6:]
    
    if ym in dic:
        if d > dic[ym]:
            dic[ym] = d
    else:
        dic[ym] = d
    
files_to_open = [path+prefix+x+y+suffix for (x,y) in dic.items()]


df = spark.read.format(form).option("header", "true").load(files_to_open)
```